# Downloaded the Imagenette2 Dataset but now how to fetch and extract? just like Tensor flow loading its own dataset?

Tags: image, conv-neural-network, imagenet

Local Path to the imagenette2 dataset

> C:\Users\khana\Ai_Project\Project\imagenette2.tar
> [image]